# Why my single-phase induction motor's velocity decreases after 100Hz?

Tags: pwm, inverter, induction-motor

I have made a single-phase inverter with control V/F using Freescale S08P and IRAMS. However when the frequency of 100hz  passes the motor decreases the velocity.
Some problem with my system or V/F is really limited?

Data:

PWM - 15Khz

Motor single-phase permanent capacitor (without it) - 1/8 HP or 1/6 HP (unreadable)

Modulation:

$$V_{Main} = \frac{V_{dc}}{2} + Vf * sin(wt)$$

$$V_{Aux} = \frac{V_{dc}}{2} + Vf * cos(wt)$$

$$V_C = \frac{Vdc}{2}$$

Comment: How much does it decrease by?  Is this happening loaded or with no load?

Comment: No Load. It Decrease to almost stop.

Comment: If your motor is normally rated at 60 Hz, then as you increase frequency the power is going to remain constant (roughly).  This means the torque is going to decrease as the frequency increases.  Eventually that torque is going to go to 0.  It is very possible that you just pushed the motor beyond the frequency it will run at.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely the type of motor you are using - it is a single-phase AC motor with a capacitor. The capacitor feeds a secondary winding in the motor that ensures the direction of the motor is always maintained. The cap and the winding form a kind-of tuned circuit that create a phase angle (usually 90 degrees) and the winding is placed at 90 degrees mechanically (usually). What happens when you change the frequency from nominal: -

[image]

This is a picture of the phase response from an LCR filter but this will be exactly the same on the type of motor you have. Frequency = 1 (middle) can be taken to be your motor's nominal running frequency (i.e. 50 or 60 Hz) - note how the phase shift is +/- 90 degrees. What happens when F doubles - that phase shift moves by 45 degrees. It's worse on a light load because the losses are smaller and the graph is steeper: -

[image]

Ignore the picture on the right and concentrate on the picture on the left. On lighter loads (higher Q factor) the phase difference when doubling the frequency can almost move a further 90 degrees - you could find a situation that if you increased the speed further, the motor may even reverse direction.

That's your problem I believe.

**EDIT**

Running the main coil and auxiliary coil at 90 degrees is the right thing to do to avoid the effects noted above - this will allow you to run slower than the rated nominal frequency of the motor. The only concern here is that you reduce voltage with reductions in frequency - this is done because the reactances of stator windings and rotor winding also reduce linearly with frequency and can take too much current and burn. The force needed to move the rotor is proportional to current so reducing voltages with reducing frequencies makes sense.

On the other hand, increasing the frequency above nominal requires an increase in voltage in order to preserve the force (supplied by magnetism aka ampere-turns) but, it's going to be a bit worse than that - the force that moves the mechanical inertia of the rotor needs to increase at higher speeds to get it to "shift" 90 degrees in a shorter period of time. This is a slippery slope because to do that means even more voltage and the potential for electrical insulation breakdown not only due to the voltage but also the heat generated at higher frequencies - remember, this type of motor is a transformer and eddy current losses in the core will increase with frequency thus creating more heat.

In short, higher than nominal frequencies means more heat due to increased eddy current losses and a significantly bigger voltage supply to more-than-maintain the ampere-turns needed to move the rotor faster than it would at nominal frequency.

Comment: 90, or 60? Not saying you are wrong, I'm just confused.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh 60? Now I'm confused - have I said 60 in my answer somewhere?

Comment: Ignore me. That was incoherent on my part. I was actually thinking about the mechanical fitting alignment, and wondering if 90 degrees was typical.

Comment: @Andy aka, Then I should correct the phase on auxiliary winding while increasing the frequency? Hummmm. I will test it now!

Comment: @fabio - that might work - at twice the frequency the reactance of the coil has doubled so you'll need to quarter the capacitance to maintain the same phase relationship. This is a little bit of speculation on my part so please tread carefully.

Comment: @Andy aka - Note: There is no capacitor connected. The 90 degrees is provided by PWM modulation (Vaux). 
I changed the program to increase/decrease degrees... but don't work. However, your explaination was great. Thanks.

Comment: @fabio - maybe the motor just isn't "man" enough for 100Hz? It wouldn't suprise me - try contacting the manufacturer maybe? Also the induction rotor reactance wil near enough double and this could make starting the motor more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I get it.
Despite my motor be commonly named "single-phase motor (mono-phase)" on market (at Brazil),  it's indeed a bi-phase ac motor.
The correct modulation is:

$$V_{Main} = \frac{V_{dc}}{2} + Vf * cos(wt)$$

$$V_{Aux} = \frac{V_{dc}}{2} - Vf * cos(wt)$$

$$V_C = \frac{V_{dc}}{2} + Vf * cos(wt + a)$$
$$a = 90º$$

Another problem are the high value on Deadtime of the PWM. When i reduced this value, the motor performance has increased.